# How to evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{8-\sqrt{x}}{8+\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{8-\sqrt{x}}{8+\sqrt{x}}$$

I tried rationalizing the numerator:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{8-\sqrt{x}}{8+\sqrt{x}} \times \dfrac{(8-\sqrt{x})}{(8-\sqrt{x})}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{64-16\sqrt{x}+x}{64-x}$$

Is this correct? how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: You have some typos(?) in your work.

Comment: Factor out x from both and cancel the terms which has x in their denominator and so you find the answer to be - 1

Comment: i think avrham is right it is -1

Comment: @JonasMeyer  y is he wrong ?

Comment: @user142634: It is right.  The version of the comment that I was responding to was wrong, but has been corrected.

Comment: @JonasMeyer What typos? thanks

Comment: E.g., do you mean denominator?  Do you mean to multiply with $\frac{8-\sqrt x}{8 - \sqrt x}$?  Otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Oh ok, I thought you can rationalize either numerator or denominator, because for example, in $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+11}-\sqrt{x^2-11}$ we rationalize the numerator...

Comment: @user437158: You can, but you did one and said the other.

Comment: @MichaelT: L'Hospitals is the brainless shortcut method to the answer. There are simpler way to evaluate this limit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try dividing each term by $\sqrt{x}$ instead. Intuitively, it is the dominating term as $x$ gets large:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{8-\sqrt{x}}{8+\sqrt{x}}
= \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\frac{8}{\sqrt x}-1}{\frac{8}{\sqrt x}+1}
= \dfrac{0-1}{0+1}
= -1
$$

Answer (score 5):

We can rewrite the expression as $$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} (-1 + \frac{16}{8 + \sqrt x})$$

The second term goes to zero, thus the limit is $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, although this may not be rigorous:

As $x\to \infty$, $\sqrt{x}$ dominates, being the highest power in both  the numerator and denominator, hence
$$\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{8−\sqrt{x}}{8+\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac {-\cancel{\sqrt{x}}}{+\cancel{\sqrt{x}}}=−1$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all get rid of the square root: since squaring is a continuous function and $\lim_{t\to\infty}t^2=\infty$, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{8-\sqrt{x}}{8+\sqrt{x}}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{8-\sqrt{t^2}}{8+\sqrt{t^2}}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{8-t}{8+t}
$$
Now you have reduced to the limit at infinity of a rational function, for which there's an easy criterion. Suppose $a_m\ne0$ and $b_n\ne0$; then
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}
  \frac{a_mt^m+a_{m-1}t^{m-1}+\dots+a_0}{b_nt^n+b_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\dots+b_0}
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}
  \frac{t^m\left(a_m+\dfrac{a_{m-1}}{t}+\dots+\dfrac{a_0}{t^m}\right)}
       {t^n\left(b_n+\dfrac{b_{n-1}}{t}+\dots+\dfrac{b_0}{t^n}\right)}
=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{a_mt^m}{b_nt^n}
$$
So this limit is

1. $\infty$ if $m>n$ and $\frac{a_m}{b_n}>0$;
2. $-\infty$ if $m>n$ and $\frac{a_m}{b_n}<0$;
3. $0$ if $n>m$
4. $\dfrac{a_m}{b_n}$ if $m=n$.

In your case $m=n=1$, $a_1=-1$ and $b_1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add two more ways of solving.

1. L'Hôpital's rule states that if $\lim_{x \to \infty}{f(x)} = \lim_{x
       \to \infty}{g(x)} = \infty$ then

   $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty}
       \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $$

   In this case

   $$
       \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{8-x^{1/2}}{8+x^{1/2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty}
       \frac{-\frac 1 2 x^{-1/2}}{\frac 1 2 x^{-1/2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} (-1) = -1
       $$
2. Let $t^2=x$. Then, $\lim_{x \to \infty} t = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x} = \infty $. Consequently:

   $$
       \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{8-\sqrt x}{8+\sqrt x} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{8-\sqrt {t^2}}{8+\sqrt {t^2}} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{8-|t|}{8+|t|} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{8-t}{8+t} = -1
       $$